# How to align divs of different parents?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'd like to have a menu that has content inside and the content is align with the other menu items.

Currently I have:

```
[- someth                      something else]
[- something         something else something]
[- some                   something else some]
```

And I want it to be aligned like this:

```
[- someth            something else          ]
[- something         something else something]
[- some              something else some     ]
```

Here is the code of what I have now, but how may I make it the way I want?

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Someth</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Something</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>something</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Some</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>some</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g1j38jph/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `jQuery` to resize the `.wrapper2` and using the same code as a fallback CSS only.

```
var size = 0;
$('.wrapper2').each(function() {
   if($(this).width() > size)
   {
      size = $(this).width();
   }
});
$('.price-wrapper2').width(size);
```

Comment: It can be done with just pure css, see my answer @Wiliam

Answer (score 4):

Something like this.

flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow. `flex: 1;` will divide flex-box in two equal parts

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrapper2 > p {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper2 > p:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Someth</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Something</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>something</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Some</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>some</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to use `width: 50%` or some other value, but it's not mobile friendly. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The first comment was to another answer, sorry about the mess, but I'll try the `text-align:right`

Comment: The solution wasn't the one I wanted, so I ended up using jQuery to make all the same `width` size and will keep the `justify-content: space-between` as a fallback CSS only. Thank you though!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `justify-content: space-between` on the primary flex container, which spaces your flex items to opposite ends of the container, use `flex: 1` on the flex items, which forces them to share container space equally.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-item > * {
  flex: 1;                        /* new */
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* optional; just for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Someth</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Something</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>something</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="wrapper1">Some</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>something else</p>
      <p>some</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but the larger `.wrapper2` should be touching the end of `.menu-item`. Is there a way to accomplish it? I tried to user `flex: 10` to `.wrapper1` and `flex: 1` to `.wrapper2`, but it ends the same way I have now.

Comment: Right. It won't work with different `flex-grow` values. Try using `flex-basis` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/g1j38jph/3/

Comment: The solution wasn't the one I wanted, so I ended up using jQuery to make all the same `width` size and will keep the `justify-content: space-between` as a fallback CSS only. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the right ratio in the CSS, here the link: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1j38jph/6/)

```
.menu,
.menu-item:first-of-type p{
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2,
.menu-item:nth-of-type(2) p, 
.menu-item:nth-of-type(3) p {
  width:50%;
}
.menu-item:nth-of-type(2) p:nth-of-type(2),
.menu-item:nth-of-type(3) p:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't simply

```css
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper1, .wrapper2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="wrapper1">
            Someth
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper2">
            <p>
                something else
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="wrapper1">
            something else
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper2">
            <p>
                something else
            </p>
            <p>
                something else
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="wrapper1">
            Some
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper2">
            <p>
                something else
            </p>
            <p>
                some
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, but that's not a really good approach, what if my first or my last `.menu-item` is the bigger one? If I change the text, I would have to change the CSS everytime, or if I have several items, I would get crazy to check wich one is bigger :). And somehow your code made the 3rd `.menu-item` `Some` text move up lol.

Comment: I made cols, not rows, that's why :)